# How to use MS Access 2010 to attach files in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access, attachment

Having an issue with an attachment field.  We use MS Access 2010 front end with a MYSQL back-end.  I have a table that contains an 'attachment' field.  It's intention is to store 2 PDF files per record.  (database is only 300 records).

When the table is built on the local side, the file attachment wizard pops up properly when clicked on in the Form allowing you to upload a single or multiple files.  However, when the table is moved over to the MYSQL end and the field type is changed to BLOB, the following error occurs;

"THE OLE object is empty.
You can't edit a bound object frame if the field in the underlying table       doesn't contain an OLE object. Right-click the field, click Insert Object, and use the dialog box to locate and add the object to the field."

Right click method isn't so bad, however it will only allow you to store one object, and not multiple files.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Attachment` datatype that can hold multiple files is quite specific to an Access database. I doubt that any server database system supports this.

If you have 2 files per record, why not create 2 BLOB fields for them?

Or if there may be more files (0..n), create a separate table for them, with an 1:n relation from the main table.

Comment: I'll give it a go.  Thanks.